# Is ubuntu 14.04 compatible with ROS Kinect Kame or Lunar? or should i update my os to 16.04?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to update to ROS Kinect or ROS Lunar. Does it have compatibility issues with ubuntu 14.04? or should i update that as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263598/is-ubuntu-14.04-compatible-with-ros-kinect-kame-or-lunar?-or-should-i-update-my-os-to-16.04?/) by [Shubhayu Das](https://answers.ros.org/users/28390/shubhayu-das/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [REP-3 - Target Platforms - Platforms by Distribution - Kinetic Kame (May 2016 - May 2021)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) and [Lunar Loggerhead (May 2017 - May 2019)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019).

So you'll have to upgrade to at least Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) to be able to use either of those.

Note that this is also clearly stated on the installation pages on the ROS wiki.

For Kinetic ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation)):

> These instructions will install the ROS Kinetic Kame distribution, **which is available for [..] Ubuntu Xenial (16.04 LTS)** [..]

For Lunar ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation)):

> These instructions will install the ROS Lunar Loggerhead distribution, **which is available for Ubuntu Zesty(17.04), Xenial (16.04 LTS)** [..]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1